# Integrate PouchDB with quick search search plugin

Tags: npm, pouchdb

I'm using [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) and trying to add [pouchdb-quick-search](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-quick-search) as plugin in **npm** way like described in it:

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-quick-search'));
```

But no success: search function is undefined.
Have anyone deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I created a file called `index.js` containing:

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-quick-search'));

var db = new PouchDB('mydb');
console.log('db.search: ' + db.search);
```

Then I ran from the command line:

```
npm install pouchdb && npm install pouchdb-quick-search
node index.js
```

And it printed out:

```
db.search: function () {
    var len = arguments.length;
    var args = new Array(len);
    var i = -1;
    while (++i < len) {
      args[i] = arguments[i];
    }
    return fun.call(this, args);
  }
```

I'm using Node v4.0.0 on Mac OS X. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can I use the plugin with bower?

Comment: Yep, but then you just add `<script src="./path/to/bower_components/pouchdb-quick-search/dist/pouchdb.quick-search.js"></script>` and that's all you need.